# Recursive view detected on hive view

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a view 'A' in "X" database, ON either of the tables A_a and A_b which will be dynamical changes. I would like to replicate this view in another database as well dynamically. I have just created another view on top of this X.A but it yields error like below:

Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Recursive view X.A detected (cycle: Y.A -> X.A -> X.A). (state=42000,code=40000)

Answer (score 1):

If the first view(X.A) created on top of X.A_a or X.A_b then it will be fine. But my automated script replaced the correct view x.A as well it should be excluded.